# Chaining values with catamorphisms

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, recursion-schemes

Suppose I have definitions as follows (where `cata` is the catamorphism):

```
type Algebra f a = f a -> a

newtype Fix f = Fx (f (Fix f)) 

unFix :: Fix f -> f (Fix f)
unFix (Fx x) = x 

cata :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata alg = alg . fmap (cata alg) . unFix
```

I was wondering if there would be some way to modify the definition of `cata` so that I could chain some object such as an `int` through it such that I could generate unique handles for things within the alg function, i.e. "a0", "a1", "a2", ..., etc.

**Edit:** To make this more clear, I'd like to be able to have some function `cata'` such that when I have something similar to the following definitions

```
data IntF a 
    = Const Int
    | Add a a

instance Functor IntF where
    fmap eval (Const i) = Const i
    fmap eval (x `Add` y) = eval x `Add` eval y

alg :: Int -> Algebra IntF String
alg n (Const i) = "a" ++ show n
alg n (s1 `Add` s2) = s1 ++ " && " ++ s2

eval = cata' alg

addExpr = Fx $ (Fx $ Const 5) `Add` (Fx $ Const 4)

run = eval addExpr
```

then `run` evaluates to "a0 && a1" or something similar, i.e. the two constants don't get labeled the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just sequence them as monads.

```
newtype Ctr a = Ctr { runCtr :: Int -> (a, Int) } -- is State Int

instance Functor Ctr
instance Applicative Ctr
instance Monad Ctr

type MAlgebra m f a = f (m a) -> m a

fresh :: Ctr Int
fresh = Ctr (\i -> (i, i+1))

data IntF a 
  = Val
  | Add a a

malg :: IntF (Ctr String) -> Ctr String
malg Val = (\x -> "a" ++ show x) <$> fresh
malg (Add x y) = (\a b -> a ++ " && " ++ b) <$> x <*> y

go = cata malg
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want something like

```
cata' :: Functor f => (Int -> f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
```

so that you can operate both on `f a` and it's index.

If that's true, here's a possible solution.

### Associated `Int`

First we define a new type which will represent `Int`-labelled functor:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data IntLabel f a = IntLabel Int (f a) deriving (Functor)    

-- This acts pretty much like `zip`.
labelFix :: Functor f => [Int] -> Fix f -> Fix (IntLabel f)
labelFix (x:xs) (Fx f) = Fx . IntLabel x $ fmap (labelFix xs) f
```

Now we can define `cata'` using `cata` and `labelFix`:

```
cata' :: Functor f => (Int -> f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata' alg = cata alg' . labelFix [1..]
  where
    alg' (IntLabel n f) = alg n f
```

**NOTE:** unique `Int`s are assigned to each layer, not each functor. E.g. for `Fix []` each sublist of the outermost list will be labelled with `2`.

### Threading effects

A different approach to the problem would be to use `cata` to produce monadic value:

```
cata :: Functor f => (f (m a) -> m a) -> Fix f -> m a
```

This is just a specialized version of `cata`. With it we can define (almost) `cat'` as

```
cata'' :: Traversable f => (Int -> f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
cata'' alg = flip evalState [1..] . cata alg'
  where
    alg' f = alg <$> newLabel <*> sequenceA f

newLabel :: State [a] a
newLabel = state (\(x:xs) -> (x, xs))
```

Note that `Traversable` instance now is needed in order to switch `f (m a)` to `m (f a)`.

However, you might want to use just a bit more specialized `cata`:

```
cata :: (Functor f, MonadReader Int m) => (f (m a) -> m a) -> Fix f -> m a
```

Comment: I've updated the question, when I use your code for `cata'`, I get the resulting string "a2 && a2" but it should be something like "a2 && a3".

Comment: Also, what is the definition of newLabel?

Comment: @user3505407 I've included definition of `newLabel`. The answer of @J. Abrahamson is a variation on my second suggestion adjusted to your edit, so you should take a closer look at his answer.